# Moving into Spotify array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, api, react-native

I'm trying to use Spotify API and to move into the Arrays.

```
const App = () => {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const [dataSource, setDataSource] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    return fetch("https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/albums?offset=0&limit=5", {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Authorization:
          "Bearer AUTH CODE "
      }
    })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(responseJson => {
        setIsLoading(false);
        // console.log(responseJson);

        // let result = Object.values(responseJson); // if I want to convert it in array
        let result = responseJson
        setDataSource(result);

      });
    }, []);


    console.log(dataSource);
```

and I get an object

```
{href: "https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/albums?o`enter code here`ffset=0&limit=5", items: Array(5) ...}
```

I would like to go into items but when i do

```
console.log(dataSource.items);
```

or

```
console.log(dataSource.items[1]);
```

I get

```
Cannot read property 'items' of undefined
```

Any idea?
Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `dataSource` state is by default `undefined`, you need to change the default value to have `items` property. The `fetch` is handling the `then` asynchronously so the data will arrive few milliseconds later and in that time the code tries to access `items` property which is missing.

You can try to initialize differently, like the following:

```
const [dataSource, setDataSource] = useState({ items: [] });
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: your solution worked perfectly. now if i do `const data = Object.values(dataSource).map(function(item) {return { item: item, ...dataSource[item]};
  })` and if I use `console.log(data[1])` I get `item: Array(5)} item: (5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]` but I don't understand how to move in it to get the values. any idea?